# In kafka, Is it possible to consume messages from topic only if topic have minimum n messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, apache-kafka-connect

Here is my case,

We have a Postgres connector on the source side and have lambda connector on the sink side. We have implemented this pipeline and it is working.

So we can get database data(update, delete, insert) on the lambda function.But we don't want that lambda function to be called on every time when there are any changes in the database. If the topic has **minimum** N changes, then we want to send that data to the lambda function.

Lambda connector has batch options advanced setting, but it is used to maximize batch size. I want to decide the minimum batch size and after that messages that are in the topic will be consumed by the consumer connector.

Answer (score 1):

> consume messages from topic only if topic have minimum n messages?

Out of the box, no, and not with Connect framework.

You can use `GetOffsetShell` or other programmatic function to check the "end offset" of the topic, **but** this is not an exact "number of messages". Then, if that meets some condition, you can start a consumer.

Plus, you will continue to send data, and may have processed data before, which is not removed from the topic, therefore the idea of "topic having N messages" doesn't really make sense. You will therefore also need to query for any *committed offsets* and *calculate the difference* (i.e. consumer lag).

---

Your other option would be to always read the topic, fetch data into an in-memory data-structure (a batch), then only process that (and commit the ending offset) once it reaches a certain size. Kafka Streams window functions could help with this ; window/aggregate the data and send out events to a new topic which will invoke the lambda.